# Testrail integration with automated tests

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testrail

I want to integrate TestRail with automated tests where I want to run test cases from testRail which calls the test cases in Jenkins and then writes the result back to TestRail itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As for writing results back to TestRail from Jenkins you can check [Railflow](https://railflow.io) jenkins plugin. Disclaimer: I'm a developer at Railflow

Answer (score 0):

In order to run test cases directly from TestRail, you'll need to first set up a [UI script and a trigger script.](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/customization/automation-trigger) The UI script will add a button that allows a user to kick the tests, and the trigger script will actually send some command to start the tests. I  would note that you'll need to call out to some external test runner that can actually kick and run the tests.

In order to get the results back into TestRail you'll need to leverage [TestRail's API](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api). This will allow you to post your results back into the desired run. You can associate your results via test case ID's and place them in either a new or existing run.